# First order autoregression

Tags: self-study, autoregressive

[image]

Hi, I don't get that how to use the variable T in this question. And how do we use these numbers we know to estimat $\beta_0$ and variables? Is there any formula for it? Thanks!

Comment: you have to show your work first, then folks will help you sort out the issues. you can't just ask for a solution. T in this case is the number of observations, i.e. 22 annual points.

Comment: @Aksakal What formula should I use here? Could you give a hint?

Comment: the biggest hint is in the question itself: "assuming stationarity". Think about what it means. Does it mean, for instance, that $E[Y_t]=E[Y_{t-1}]$?